# Резервное копирование MySQL

Tags: mysql, cron, резервное-копирование

Как можно сделать резервное копирование MySQL с удаленного сервера, может есть бесплатное ПО или можно как то создать  при помощи cron только не на текущем сервере а удаленно?

Comment: *только не на текущем сервере* — это, видимо, ключевой момент. какой смысл вы вкладываете в это ограничение? чем именно оно продиктовано?

Comment: на том сервере где лежит сайт мало места для бэкапов, нужно сохранять все бекапы на другом

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательная утилита [`mysqldump`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/mysqldump.html):

```
> mysqldump -uLOGIN -PPORT -hHOST -pPASS DBNAME > dump.txt
```

Расположите эту строчку в `bash` скрипте и запускайте в `cron`.

Answer (score 2):

> на том сервере где лежит сайт мало места для бэкапов, нужно сохранять все бекапы на другом

с помощью, например, программы *ssh* (и демона *sshd* на удалённой машине), можно запускать какую-нибудь команду/программу на удалённой машине, а вывод её получать (и, при необходимости, сохранять) — на локальной.

пример:

```
$ ssh удалённая.машина mysqldump параметры > dump.file
```

на удалённой машине будет запущена программа `mysqldump параметры`, а вывод её будет сохранён в файле `dump.file` на вашей локальной машине (точнее, на той, где вы выполняете приведённую команду).